# Control system -- closed-loop system problem

Tags: homework, control-theory

Given a closed-loop system as shown below:
[image]

Suppose that \$x(t) = u(t)\$ and \$d(t)=0.5u(t)\$. Determine the output response of \$y(t)\$ and it's steady state at \$t\rightarrow \infty\$.

I've tried to solve the problem but I'm not sure about my answer since my professor only gave us a brief introduction to this material. Here's my attempt:

I know that \$Y(s)=\mathcal{L}\{y(t)\}=\frac{1}{s}\$ and \$D(s)=\mathcal{L}\{d(t)\}=\frac{1}{2s}\$, then

\$
\begin{aligned}
Y(s)&= P\cdot C \cdot \left(X(s)-Y(s)\right) + D(s)\\
Y(s)\left(1-\frac{9}{s+1}\right)&=\frac{9}{s(s+1)}+\frac{1}{2s}\\
\frac{s+10}{s+1}Y(s)&=\frac{9}{s(s+1)}+\frac{1}{2s}\\
Y(s)&=\frac{s^2+19s}{2s^2(s+10)}
\end{aligned}
\$

Using inverse Laplace transform

\$ 
\begin{aligned}
y(t)&=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{Y(s)\}\\
&=\frac{19u(t)-9e^{-10t}}{20}
\end{aligned}
\$

For the steady-state value, I used the final value theorem

\$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} y(t) &= \lim_{s \rightarrow 0} sY(s)\\
&=\lim_{s \rightarrow 0} s\frac{s^2+19s}{2s^2(s+10)}\\
&=\frac{19}{20}
\end{aligned}
\$

Any mistake?

Comment: Seems  correct to me , only thing you can avoid here to use final value theorem if you already got your response in time domain and you can get steady state just taking limit t tends to infinity in y(t)

Comment: This site supports LaTeX formatting for your equations -- enclose inline equations in `\$` and enclose regular math mode equations in `$$`. Can you convert the images of your equations to LaTeX formatting (presumably you have the LaTeX source, so you can just copy and paste)?

Comment: @Null oh I didn't know I should add '\' before the dollar sign. I'll change it, thanks!